# why on my toggle star.fill changes to star.square.fill

Tags: swiftui

So I only want it to star, change to green but instead around it changes and itself remains white.

```
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
       Toggle(isOn: $favourites) {
           Image(systemName: favourites ? "star.fill" : "star")
            }
            .tint(.green)
        }
```

[around of the star green only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR9NA.png)

Comment: Have you tried using .foregroundColor instead of .tint?

Comment: this works but this time it becomes green star with blue background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't want to use a Toggle, but just a regular button instead.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
            favourites.toggle()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: favourites ? "star.fill" : "star")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bjorn this is perfect. Definitely in dark mode, two different tints become a disaster.

Answer (score -1):

The tint needs to placed on the **Image** and not the **Toggle**. Like so:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
       Toggle(isOn: $favourites) {
           Image(systemName: favourites ? "star.fill" : "star")
               .tint(.green)
       }
       .tint(.white)
    }
```

Comment: this makes it surround blue instead of white.

Comment: @BurakBirinci oh yes, I have edited the answer to remedy this... Hope that works now

Comment: it was making full white so i tried inside image foregroundcolor(.green) and toggle side tint(.white) and it worked perfectly. thank you so much for help chris.

Comment: This approach is not very good since you are hardcoding the tint to white, so if you run the app in dark mode you will once again have a background, just in white this time.